# Newbie noise reduction question

Tags: music, noise-reduction, noise-cancelling

I have a musical audio track, where I can isolate particular sounds.

Are there any practical steps that I can take to reduce the noise of the isolated samples from the rest of the track, in order to attempt to separate the components of a song for mixing?

Comment: There are _many_ questions already asked, with many answers.  Please have a look.  If none of those suggestions are helpful, you'll be in a much better place to ask a specific question.

Comment: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/69/sound-off-on-noise-reduction?rq=1 http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/another-noise-related-question?rq=1  http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/26473/best-noise-reduction-methods?rq=1